# ftello function is undeclared

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, large-files

I'm trying to get current position of file that over 2GB on 32bit OS.

I defined LARGEFILE_SOURCE and FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 options like below.
APP_CFLAGS := -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

And if I compile on ndk, It says
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ftello'; did you mean 'ftell'?

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe it is the same issue as this one [android-error-use-of-undeclared-identifier-fseeko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571842/android-error-use-of-undeclared-identifier-fseeko)

Comment: @hko I also added -D__ANDROID_API__=24 option too. But it's not working

Comment: @hko And I set minsdkVersion to 24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah Now I got it..

To set minSdkVersion in compiler option, I have to do like below.
APP_PLATFORM := android-24

Thanks for your advice!